# Python list into csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I created a scraper to get info from a website using a for loop and created a list with each loop.
The result is what I expected but I'm having a hard time to put this info altogether into a csv file. My intention is to create 4 rows where the corresponding url, location, etc, will match but I maybe the way that I set my loops is making it harder?

I thought the the follow syntax would do the trick but nah. It only prints all the urls in the same row.
I got to print all the info but they were still in the same row.

```
with open('trademe.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['URL', 'Price', 'Location', 'Flatmates'])
    writer.writerow([link, price, loc, mates])
```

By the way, this is the code so far;

```
trademe = urlopen(url)
trademe_html = soup(trademe.read(), "html.parser")
trademe.close()

link=[]
for i in trademe_html.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'dotted'}):
    link.append('URL: www.trademe.co.nz'+i.a['href'])
    print('URL: www.trademe.co.nz'+i.a['href'])

price=[]
for i in trademe_html.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'flatmates-list-view-card-price'}):
    price.append('Price and availability: ' + i.text.strip())
    print('Price and availability: ' + i.text)

loc=[]
for i in trademe_html.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'flatmates-card-subtitle'}):
    loc.append('Location: ' + i.text)
    print('Location: ' + i.text)
    
mates=[]
for i in trademe_html.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'flatmates-card-existing-flatmates'}):
    mates.append(i.text.strip())
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You've set the newline to ```''```.   Shouldn't it be ```\n```?

Comment: hey @ewong thanks! I forgot to mention that I tried setting the newline='\n' and it didn't work. I tried adding \n at the end of my loop and it works if I print it inside of my IDE. However it doesn't work on the csv file somehow.

Answer (score 1):

- Insert your data into a `pandas` `DataFrame`
- Use the `to_csv` function in `pandas`

Pandas makes it really easy to export a DataFrame to csv with headers

Comment: hi @topgunner, thanks for answering my question! I did use pandas dataframe but I still can't get to the desired result. The following code writes all the info in the corresponding header but altogether in the same row

fields = ['URL', 'Price', 'Location', 'Flatmates'] 
  
rows = [ link, 
         price, 
         loc, 
         mates], 

  

 
with open('agalu.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as csv_file: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file) 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields) 
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)